# What sim card shall I get to travel in the Cyclades Islands and have data?

Tags: internet, greece, mobile-operators

I'm traveling to Greece and will spend most of my time in the Cyclades Islands. On arrival at Athens airport or in the city I would like to pick a local SIM card for the travel.

#### Question

Could you recommend some operator that cover this area and provide 4G data connection?

Comment: 4G network is pretty good in Greece, I have more trouble in France

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main operators with coverage of 4G but I am not sure if Cyclades have 4G availability. The companies are [Cosmote](https://www.cosmote.gr/), [Vodaphone](http://www.vodafone.gr/portal/client/cms/viewCmsPage.action?pageId=1032) and [Wind](https://www.wind.gr/en/). I would recommend that you e-mail them in order to tell you if they have 4G coverage in Cyclades and also tell you which product you can use (there are some bureaucratic stuff needed to get a pre-paid card) as a tourist.

Update: After doing some research I found that all 3 companies have 4G coverage in Santorini (Thera island) and most of Cyclades.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answer. If you are travelling from anywhere within the EU, you are now covered by "[Free Roaming Charges](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/telecoms-internet/mobile-roaming-costs/index_en.htm)".

That means, should you wish to, you can keep your original sim at no extra cost to your original plan as long as you fall within your companies "fair usage" policy.